# The docker container doesn't working Kubernetes Plugin jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-helm

I deployed version 2.319.3 of Jenkins helm but I have an issue stranger with the container docker. My version Kubernetes: 1.22.6 (aks).

ERROR:

docker build -t registry.azurecr.io/test:develop-v81.
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Test another docker command:

- docker info
  Client:
  Context:    default
  Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info

My agents pods config:

apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
labels:
jenkins/jenkins-jenkins-agent: "true"
jenkins/label-digest: "500b4f18aee87616849e4f4c2435020898e34aa0"
jenkins/label: "jenkins-jenkins-agent"
name: "default-gvzg5"
spec:
containers:

- args:

  - "********"
  - "default-gvzg5"
    env:
  - name: "JENKINS_SECRET"
    value: "********"
  - name: "JENKINS_TUNNEL"
    value: "jenkins-agent.whitelabel.svc.cluster.local:50000"
  - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_NAME"
    value: "default-gvzg5"
  - name: "JENKINS_NAME"
    value: "default-gvzg5"
  - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR"
    value: "/home/jenkins/agent"
  - name: "JENKINS_URL"
    value: "http://jenkins.whitelabel.svc.cluster.local:8080/jenkins"
    image: "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.11.2-4"
    imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    name: "jnlp"
    resources:
    limits: {}
    requests: {}
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
    name: "volume-0"
    readOnly: false
  - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
    name: "workspace-volume"
    readOnly: false
    workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
- args:

  - "9999999"
    command:
  - "sleep"
    image: "docker:20.10"
    imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    name: "docker2"
    resources:
    limits: {}
    requests: {}
    securityContext:
    privileged: true
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
    name: "volume-0"
    readOnly: false
  - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
    name: "workspace-volume"
    readOnly: false
    workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
    hostNetwork: false
    nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
    restartPolicy: "Never"
    serviceAccountName: "default"
    volumes:
- hostPath:
  path: "/var/run/docker.sock"
  name: "volume-0"
- emptyDir:
  medium: ""
  name: "workspace-volume"

The docker container should be working. This is working with the old version of jenkins 2.277.1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused for the Kubernetes version. You can't execute Daemon docker /var/run/docker.sock with privileges. You can try to fix this with Kaniko Container or use a Virtual Machine with docker and privileges. Thank you.